Django - Unit test RuntimeError model class doesn't declare an explicit app_label
Heyo all. I'm having an issue running unit tests in my new Django project.
Whenever I try running them inside PyCharm, I am getting the error:
ImportError: Failed to import test module: backend.dtva_app.models
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/unittest/loader.py", line 470, in _find_test_path
    package = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/unittest/loader.py", line 377, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/tumpa/PycharmProjects/appon_dtva/backend/../backend/dtva_app/models/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .user import CustomUser
  File "/Users/tumpa/PycharmProjects/appon_dtva/backend/../backend/dtva_app/models/user.py", line 7, in <module>
    class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
  File "/Users/tumpa/PycharmProjects/appon_dtva/backend/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 134, in __new__
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Model class backend.dtva_app.models.user.CustomUser doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.

Some other files that might be useful are:
The INSTALLED_APPS:
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt',
    'corsheaders',
    'dtva_app',
    'drf_spectacular',
]

My app is called dtva_app and this is the apps.py config:
class DtvaAppConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'dtva_app'

This is the CustomUser model being mentioned:
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField("email address", unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    @property
    def full_name(self):
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"

Additionally, all the tests are being recognized, the rest of the app works normally, the endpoints, models, migrations, views, etc.. Everything is fine except running unit tests.
Also, everything is imported in __init__.py files correctly and running the unit tests from a terminal outside of PyCharm brings the same results.
Any ideas?
UPDATE
I added a class Meta with app_label to my CustomUser model and the error disappeared, but now I am getting the following error:
RuntimeError: Conflicting 'customuser_groups' models in application 'dtva_app': <class 'dtva_app.models.user.CustomUser_groups'> and <class 'backend.dtva_app.models.user.CustomUser_groups'>.

